# Meteor + LitElement (Polymer 3) issue with importing

Tags: javascript, meteor, polymer-3.x, lit-element, lit-html

I had an issue with importing the LitElement module into a Meteor project:

I'm starting a new test project with Meteor 1.7+ and am using LitElement for a few components.

I installed Meteor like so:

```
meteor create meteor-lithtml --release 1.7.1-beta.29 --bare
```

I installed like so:

```
meteor npm install --save @polymer/lit-element
```

My node_modules directory looks like so:

[image]

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "@polymer/lit-element": "^0.5.2",
    "@vaadin/router": "^1.0.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/index.js",
      "server": "server/index.js"
    }
  }
}
```

The typical way I see lit-element imported is not working...

Just adding an index.js file and importing the lit-element module generates errors.  If I remove the import from the index.js file, the errors go away.

```
\\ client\index.js
import { LitElement, html } from '@polymer/lit-element';
```

The very first error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

modules.js?hash=182125a3fa97eaa24f6d313584ca593c3aed2103:984
```

Points to this location:

[image]

Expanding node_modules to look into this file:

[image]

Why am I getting the unexpected { token?

---

NOTE: I'm asking this question here just in case a Meteor user stumbles by with the same issue and needs help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case we have any more Meteor users stop by with an issue like this, here are the references to the explanation & solution:

explanation:  https://forums.meteor.com/t/litelement-import-litelement-html/45042/8?u=aadams

solution: https://github.com/aadamsx/meteor-lithtml/pull/1